# Can DOM matches logic be applied to an LWC LightingElement?

Tags: lightning-web-components, dom

One problem stopping [Mobiscroll calendar working inside a LWC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289726/mobiscroll-calendar-working-inside-a-lwc) is described in the **PS** to that question. An equivalent of [element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches#Syntax) (AKA `element.matchesSelector`) needs to be implemented for an LWC [LightningElement](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/blob/master/packages/lwc/types.d.ts#L16), as neither of those methods is supported. There is also no `parentNode` property and AFAIK you can't access the `document`. These restrictions block the common [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches#Polyfill) and its `parentNode` equivalent.

So I'm starting to form the opinion that there is no way to implement [element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches#Syntax) logic applied to an LWC `LightningElement` given the access restrictions. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my hacking around in the JavaScript debugger, the answer is **no**.

Real Phil W's answer and my comments there for more info.

Answer (score 2):

An LWC effectively has a document fragment within its "template". Given that you can access the this.template to access the rendered fragment for the LWC - albeit without the content of child components, which is hidden in those components' shadow DOMs. The template then provides you access to running selector-based queries using [this.template.querySelectorAll](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_dom_work).

It seems to me all you then have to do is see if the given element is a member of the node set returned by that call to determine whether it matches the selector.

If that doesn't work for you, please explain more here what you're trying to do (I must say I didn't read all the other linked items! Lazy me...)

Comment: HI Phil, May well be that starting from the `template` is the answer. Will try that tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Breakpointing in the Mobiscroll JavaScript, `element.toString()` returns "SecureElement: [object HTMLInputElement]{ key: {"namespace":"cvnp"} }" which based on this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.security_locker_global_access) blocks access to any extra `@api` method added to the component or external code access to the `template`. Understandable from a security viewpoint, but I think blocks this approach.