# Illegal Invocation error resourceTimelineYear view in LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, fullcalendar

I am implementing fullcalendar 4.4.0 in a salesforce LWC component and I have successfully loaded the calendar but when selecting the resourceTimelineYear view I get the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
throws at https://d80000000miexeao-- ngsched.lightning.force.com/resource/1646079060000/fullcalendar_4_4_0/packages/core/main.js:129:30 TypeError: Illegal invocation
at elementMatches (main.js:129:30)
at Object.findChildren (main.js:153:34)
at TimelineSlats.renderDates (main.js:646:73)
at TimelineSlats.render (main.js:613:18)
at TimelineSlats.Component.receiveProps (main.js:3957:22)
at TimeAxis.render (main.js:1349:24)
at TimeAxis.Component.receiveProps (main.js:3957:22)
at ResourceTimelineView.render (main.js:581:27)
at ResourceTimelineView.Component.receiveProps (main.js:3957:22)
at CalendarComponent.renderView (main.js:6304:18)
```

I am only loading static sample data at the moment, here is the JS:

```javascript
initializeCalendar() {

     var calendarEl = this.template.querySelector('div.container div.calendar');
     var calendar;

     // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-inner-html
     calendarEl.innerHTML = '';

     calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
         schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
         timeZone: 'UTC',
         plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'resourceTimeline' ],
         header: { center: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek, listWeek, resourceTimelineDay, resourceTimelineYear' }, // buttons for switching between views
         events: this.events,
         selectable: true,
         unselectAuto: false,
         resources: [
             { id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B', occupancy: 40, eventColor: 'green' },
             { id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C', occupancy: 40, eventColor: 'orange' },
             { id: 'd', title: 'Auditorium D', occupancy: 40, children: [
                 { id: 'd1', title: 'Room D1', occupancy: 10 },
                 { id: 'd2', title: 'Room D2', occupancy: 10 }
             ] },
             { id: 'e', title: 'Auditorium E', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'f', title: 'Auditorium F', occupancy: 40, eventColor: 'red' },
             { id: 'g', title: 'Auditorium G', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'h', title: 'Auditorium H', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'i', title: 'Auditorium I', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'j', title: 'Auditorium J', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'k', title: 'Auditorium K', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'l', title: 'Auditorium L', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'm', title: 'Auditorium M', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'n', title: 'Auditorium N', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'o', title: 'Auditorium O', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'p', title: 'Auditorium P', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'q', title: 'Auditorium Q', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'r', title: 'Auditorium R', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 's', title: 'Auditorium S', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 't', title: 'Auditorium T', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'u', title: 'Auditorium U', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'v', title: 'Auditorium V', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'w', title: 'Auditorium W', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'x', title: 'Auditorium X', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'y', title: 'Auditorium Y', occupancy: 40 },
             { id: 'z', title: 'Auditorium Z', occupancy: 40 }
             ],

         eventRender: function(info) {
             let name = "tooltip";
             let arr = info.el.className.split(" ");
             if (arr.indexOf(name) == -1) {
                 info.el.className += " " + name;
             }

             let node = document.createElement("span");                
             let textnode = document.createTextNode(info.event.extendedProps.placementstatus);
             node.appendChild(textnode);

             node.className = "tooltiptext" ;                           
             info.el.appendChild(node);
         },

         dateClick: function(info) {
             console.log('bw: clicked ' + info.dateStr);
         },

         select: function(info) {
             console.log('bw: selected ' + info.startStr + ' to ' + info.endStr);
         }

     });

     calendar.render();     
 }
```

I need to get a resource gantt view in my component so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [fullcalendar line 129 in GitHub](https://github.com/mtgr1020/blog-demo/blob/7633465fcb329ebaae64cdba6fe5d8df1e5f3435/fullcalendar-4.4.0/packages/core/main.js#L129), the code is attemoting to use a `matches` function. And that won't work per [Can DOM matches logic be applied to an LWC LightingElement?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/290245/can-dom-matches-logic-be-applied-to-an-lwc-lightingelement). So this part of this version of this library appears to not be compatible with LWC.

Others have had problems too. Look through these [fullcalendar](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullcalendar) posts here.

Comment: So is there any options or other solutions for implementing a gantt chart in lwc that you know of? Or another way to get the fullcalendar functionality into Salesforce?

Comment: Hi Bill, I'm not aware of any but haven't really looked.

Comment: Thanks, I switched to using a labs project that does a gantt chart based on your feedback, for anyone interested... https://github.com/appiphony/gantt-chart